# Merge separate vertices residing at the same coordinates

Tags: edit-mode, vertices

Is there a way how to merge vertices that are exactly at the same X/Y/Z coordinates?

I mean like: select all vertices and make it for all at once (not going one-by-one pair manually as there may be zillions of such instances!).

But maybe funnily enough, at the moment I actually do exactly that: switch view to Wireframe, go to Edit mode, select vertices occupying specific space, press M and select Merge at center, press H to temporarily hide that such already "healed" vertice (so I would only see those that are still not "cured"), and so on until I do it for all the vertices in the object, which is extremely tidious work to do.

I found out that with some objects there are separate vertices at exact same spot making an object not connected "as one" (so to speak).

What I am up to is to find a way that would merge such vertices making previously separated faces into one interconnected surface, that is: not surface made out of separate triangles where each triangle has its own set of vertices, but rather share vertices among each other if those vertices are at the same exact coordinates (I hope I explain my point as I am not native english speaker).

Reason why I am doing this is mainly because when I do UV mapping it comes as bunch of groups of UV faces instead of one whole object + it also make my other software crash if I export such object into OBJ file.

Comment: Hello :). *Mesh > Clean up > Merge by distance* is what you're looking for.

Comment: yes, that made the trick, thanks!